# How to highlight long paragraphs?

Tags: vim, highlight

I know how to highlight long lines. Either :

```
:match ErrorMsg '\%>140v.\+'
```

which I rather prefer to the "colorcolumn way" :

```
:set colorcolumn=140
```

So, for instance, the text :

> Vim is a text editor written by B. Moolenaar and first released
>   publicly in 1991. It is based on the vi editor common to Unix-like
>   systems. Vim is free and open source software.

gets highlighted starting with "Vim is free, etc…"

But how can I achieve the same result for a paragraph (in this example, 3 lines) such as :

```
[Empty line]
Vim is a text editor written by B. Moolenaar and first released publicly in 1991. 
It is based on the vi editor common to Unix-like systems. 
Vim is free and open source software
[Empty line]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: then the whole document would be displayed in same (highlighted) color right? because your document is made up of "paragraphs" and empty lines. or I mis-understand the question?

Comment: @Kent : that's it, exactly. And those paragraphs may be (this is pure text, not code) made of 1, or 2 or 3, etc... lines, those paragraphs being separated by a single line. My wish is to see - in that example - all the paragraphs that are > 140 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult, because you have to specify (in a single regular expression)

1. the condition of *paragraphs* (which I assume to be lines separated by at most a single newline; i.e. empty lines create new paragraphs)
2. the counting of characters (highlight after 140 characters)

Here's the best I've achieved; it still somehow matches "into" following paragraphs if the current one is too small:

```
:match ColorColumn /\%(\%^\|\n\n\)\%(\%(.\+\n\)*.*\)\&\_.\{140}\%(\zs.\|\n\zs.\)/
```

Explanation:

- anchored at the beginning of the buffer or an empty line
- match non-empty line(s)
- and additional characters AND
- match 140 characters and/or newlines
- then start a match on the following character, or if that it a newline (which doesn't show up right), the next character after it

I'd be happy if someone improves on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, there seems to be a little glitch : it only works for 3-lines paragraphs. This may be due to the fact that "it still somehow matches "into" following paragraphs if the current one is too small". But as I have just commented @Kent (I should have been more precise) those paragraphs may be made of 1, or 2 or 3, etc... lines, those paragraphs being separated by a single line. A paragraph < 140 characters should be considered as correct. This induces me to ask you - if you have time enough - to explain your regex. Anyhow, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an explanation; in theory, the regexp should work (I think); maybe some Vim implementation limitations prevents its use.

Comment: tried again, and it worked nicely. Thanks for the answer, and for your explanations (btw, this regex is not for faint hearted beginners, like me ...)